# force content to string in typescript / javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, shell

I'm in a situation where I will need to pass in a shell bash script from node. This script breaks template literals since it contains variables like

> ${foo}

So I want to completely ignore syntax like

> " $ '

And so on. What alternatives do you see for accomplishing this?

I have considered using JSON somehow but did not succeed, maybe I should encode the content?

Comment: what are you doing with the string? why are you using template literals?

Comment: it's a multiline bash script i want to write as a const. it will be executed by the OS not the js at all.

Comment: Did you try escaping the `$` character ?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't escaping what you are looking for ?

```
const str = `\${im-escaped}` // '${im-escaped}'
```